# Why do GCC's linker-options (as per dumpspec) contain as-needed?

Tags: 18.04, gcc, ld

Within the specs of gcc (retrieved via `-dumpspecs`) in Ubuntu 18.04 (7.3.0-16ubuntu3) the link-section shows the explicit mention of the option `as-needed` (passed to ld). This influences linked libraries of the executable, among others surely.

The man-pages of `ld` seems to imply that the default is `no-as-needed`. GCC on Debian does *not* implicitly set `as-needed` so sticks with this default.

Why does Ubuntu's GCC has this option set?

Comment: Spec file? Ubuntu doesn't use spec files, those are for RPMs.

Comment: @muru, Yeah, I was talking about the `dumpspecs`-option of gcc. Corrected my question

Comment: That's a great question, as this breaks a lot of stuff which works fine on other systems. I really wish this were at least documented somewhere but AFAICS this is not the case.